# Will CPU context switching during semaphore usage create a deadlock?

Tags: operating-system, mutex, semaphore

Given these two threads trying to update a global variable 'var'.

Thread A

1. MutexAcquire()
2. ++var
3. MutexRelease()

Thread B

1. MutexAcquire()
2. ++var
3. MutexRelease()

What will happen in following scenario,

1. Thread A  executes MutexAcquire()
2. OS switches context to Thread B
3. Now thread B keeps waiting for Thread A to release Mutex. But thread A is switched out by the OS.

Is it not a classic DeadLock problem? How does such a case is solved in modern computers. Who ensures that the OS will not switch Thread A until it finish releasing Mutex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not. Thread B will be switched out by the OS at some point and Thread A will be able to release the mutex.

In practice you won't need to wait for Thread B to be switched out, as it will suspend its execution willing and explicitly. If you want to know how exactly this is done in modern OSes, you can check my answer on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340284/mutex-vs-semaphore-how-to-implement-them-not-in-terms-of-the-other/362533#362533).